# Свайп меню в RecyclerView, как?

Tags: android

Нужно прикрутить свайп меню в RecyclerView, как реализовать? Может есть библиотеки?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Вопрос не где найти, а как сделать, а ответом стала ссылка на библиотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Есть такие либы. Вот пример ключевиков для поиска: [android recyclerview swipe menu](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=android%20recyclerview%20swipe%20menu)
2. Вот первая ссылка на одну из реализаций на `GitHub` - [SwipeMenu](https://github.com/TUBB/SwipeMenu)

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал вот эту [ТЫК](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)

А вообще нужные либы можно искать на [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/), там их огромное кол-во